# Issue importing MNIST dataset from sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, mnist

As written in pg. 79 of Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and Tensorflow, I tried to import the MNIST data liked the book told me. The code didn't work, and I looked at other stackoverflow questions & github issue, but neither of those solutions worked, so I wanted to ask if anyone knows the solution. Thanks again for helping me solve this issue.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
minst = fetch_mldata('MNIST Original')
```

Comment: how did you install sklearn ?

Comment: @endive1783 I have "scikit-learn-1.0.2 and "scipy-1.8.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `fetch_mldata` has been rerplaced in sklearn, you should use `fetch_openml` instead :

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784')
```

However I am not sure weither the book is up to date with recent versions of sklearn, you should probably downgrade your sklearn version to the one used in the book or use a book that would be up to date with the current version.